# Matching on a variable and using the spread function to reshape data

Tags: r, dplyr, matching, tidyr

I have a dataframe (lets call it df1) that looks something like this...

```
Date                Price       Product Key
2014-08-06          10          00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715
2014-08-06          56          00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715
2014-09-15          81          000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8
2014-06-04          73          000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8
2015-01-19          44          000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae
2015-05-23          20          000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae
2014-07-21          0.75        ddc8f2e2-3496-8a71-8d1019d2651c
```

There are other variables in the dataframe but we will ignore them for now, as I do not require them.

The dataset has many different dates and product keys, this is just an example. What I want to do is exact match all products with the same product key and then extract all products with that one product key into a column of it's own. (Which should give me back around 100+ columns, each column having their own unique product key but also keeping their respective dates and prices (and other variables that I haven't included), that I can then work with)

My desired output would look something like in the image below:
[image: output example]

As you can see each product key in their new column still corresponds to their respective dates/price/other variables. Obviously there would be more than two product keys per column but this is just for an example.

I have tried various grep functions and dplyr functions but I don't seem to be getting anywhere? The main issue for me is the initial matching process within one column and being able to keep product keys next to their relevant dates and prices. I hope this makes sense - please let me know if I can make this any clearer.

```
    Date        price_currentday    json_productkey                        pk                 pk_val   

    2014-08-06          10          00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715        Product_Key_1      00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715  
    2014-08-06          56          00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715        Product_Key_1      00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715  
    2014-09-15          81          000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8        Product_Key_2      000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8 
    2014-06-04          73          000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8        Product_Key_2      000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8 
    2015-01-19          44          000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae        Product_Key_3      000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae
    2015-05-23          20          000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae        Product_Key_3      000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae
    2014-07-21          0.75        ddc8f2e2-3496-8a71-8d1019d2651c        Product_Key_4      ddc8f2e2-3496-8a71-8d1019d2651c
```

Comment: Please post expected output

Comment: Add your desired output (in terms of output df) in your question. Also, add output returned by `dput(head(yourinputdf))`

Comment: @PoGibas I have now added an example of what I want my expected output to look like. I hope this makes my question clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @Santosh I have now added an example of what I want my expected output to look like. I hope this makes my question clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1$pk = paste("Product_Key", as.numeric(factor(
  df1$Product_Key, levels = unique(df1$Product_Key)
)), sep = "_")

df1$pk_val = df1$Product_Key

tidyr::spread(df1, key = pk, value = pk_val)
        Date Price                     Product_Key                   Product_Key_1
# 1 2014-06-04 73.00 000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8                            <NA>
# 2 2014-07-21  0.75 ddc8f2e2-3496-8a71-8d1019d2651c                            <NA>
# 3 2014-08-06 10.00 00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715 00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715
# 4 2014-08-06 56.00 00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715 00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715
# 5 2014-09-15 81.00 000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8                            <NA>
# 6 2015-01-19 44.00 000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae                            <NA>
# 7 2015-05-23 20.00 000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae                            <NA>
#                     Product_Key_2                   Product_Key_3                   Product_Key_4
# 1 000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8                            <NA>                            <NA>
# 2                            <NA>                            <NA> ddc8f2e2-3496-8a71-8d1019d2651c
# 3                            <NA>                            <NA>                            <NA>
# 4                            <NA>                            <NA>                            <NA>
# 5 000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8                            <NA>                            <NA>
# 6                            <NA> 000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae                            <NA>
# 7                            <NA> 000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae                            <NA>
```

It re-orders your rows, but if you have something to sort by that can be easily fixed.

---

Using this data:

```
df1 = read.table(text = "Date                Price       Product_Key
2014-08-06          10          00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715
2014-08-06          56          00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715
2014-09-15          81          000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8
2014-06-04          73          000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8
2015-01-19          44          000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae
2015-05-23          20          000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae
2014-07-21          0.75        ddc8f2e2-3496-8a71-8d1019d2651c",
                 header = T)
```

Also works with the new data, using a relatively old `tidyr` version 0.6.3.

```
df2 = read.table(text = "Date        price_currentday    json_productkey                        pk                 pk_val   
    2014-08-06          10          00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715        Product_Key_1      00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715  
    2014-08-06          56          00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715        Product_Key_1      00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715  
    2014-09-15          81          000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8        Product_Key_2      000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8 
    2014-06-04          73          000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8        Product_Key_2      000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8 
    2015-01-19          44          000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae        Product_Key_3      000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae
    2015-05-23          20          000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae        Product_Key_3      000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae
    2014-07-21          0.75        ddc8f2e2-3496-8a71-8d1019d2651c        Product_Key_4      ddc8f2e2-3496-8a71-8d1019d2651c",
                 header = T)

tidyr::spread(df2, key = pk, value = pk_val)
#         Date price_currentday                 json_productkey                   Product_Key_1
# 1 2014-06-04            73.00 000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8                            <NA>
# 2 2014-07-21             0.75 ddc8f2e2-3496-8a71-8d1019d2651c                            <NA>
# 3 2014-08-06            10.00 00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715 00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715
# 4 2014-08-06            56.00 00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715 00020e32-3ae8-b7fa-8ecd53a64715
# 5 2014-09-15            81.00 000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8                            <NA>
# 6 2015-01-19            44.00 000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae                            <NA>
# 7 2015-05-23            20.00 000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae                            <NA>
#                     Product_Key_2                   Product_Key_3                   Product_Key_4
# 1 000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8                            <NA>                            <NA>
# 2                            <NA>                            <NA> ddc8f2e2-3496-8a71-8d1019d2651c
# 3                            <NA>                            <NA>                            <NA>
# 4                            <NA>                            <NA>                            <NA>
# 5 000340b8-9ee5-b2cb-60fb50bacac8                            <NA>                            <NA>
# 6                            <NA> 000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae                            <NA>
# 7                            <NA> 000458f1-1297-a2fd-9304a2fdb6ae                            <NA>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. The first part of this works, although it replaces the actual product key with "Product_Key_1" etc which hadn't been my intention. I wanted to keep the product key just in case I needed it for future reference. I've been having problems with the tidyr line with an error message for the value column - i've played around with this a bit but had no luck. Could this sort of thing be done using the mutate function as that adds extra columns whilst keeping the initial ones? If so, how would you go about it? Thanks for your input!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about "replacing the actual product key with Product_Key_1", the Product_Key_n columns in my result match the output image you show. To keep the original column around, duplicate it first (see edits). No, this can't be done easily with mutate.

Comment: As for the error message, I can't help without knowing the error. If you post sample data that shows the error (as well as the error message itself) then I can have a look. Do note that I used a standard column name with an undescore, `Product_Key`, rather than the nonstandard `Product Key` with space (which you maybe have?). Spaces in column names are trouble. Renaming columns is easy. (`names(df1) = make.names(names(df1))` is the lazy way, it will replace spaces with dots.)

Comment: The error message i'm getting now is Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2) i'm not quite sure what i'm doing wrong as i've followed your instructions perfectly? I've probably got confused about what you're referring to with pk_val

Comment: Can you confirm that it works on the sample data at the bottom of my question? If so, then I need you to find sample data that demonstrates the error and share that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159085/discussion-between-jay-j-and-gregor).